# Neo4j-shell query result size in MB

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any way to get from Neo4j a size in KB/MB/GB of a cypher query achieved result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know a way to do this in Neo4j shell. However you can use a command line tool like `curl` using the option `-w` to emit the download size:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "Match (n:Person) return n limit 10"}]}'
 http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit 
-w "result size %{size_download}\n"
```